# Rscript file path with space

Tags: r, cmd, whitespace, rscript

I am trying to run the following R script in windows shell:

```
Rscript C:/Documents/Folder name containing space/myscript.txt
```

In this case I get the error:

```
Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:/Documents/Folder': No such file or directory
```

However when I use quotation marks (tried single double and triple as was suggested in other posts) I get the following error:

```
Rscript "C:/Documents/Folder name containing space/myscript.txt"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I can't find a way to get around the space problem and changing the file location so there are no white-spaces is not an option for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Further Clarifications:**

The issue I am having is not directly related to R but rather to to having the file path that contains spaced being passed to Rscript.

In the documentations, Rsript should be used in the following way:

```
Rscript [options] [-e expr [-e expr2 ...] | file] [args]
```

It is also noted that:

*Spaces are allowed in expression and file (but will need to be protected from the shell in use, if any, for example by enclosing the argument in quotes).*

However trying to enclose the file path in quotes results in the error

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

**To avoid confusion**, running `Rscript C:/Documents/Folder_name/myscript.txt` works fine when the path doesn't contain any spaces as does `Rscript "C:/Documents/Folder_name/myscript.txt"`.

Comment: Would that make it `Rscript C:/Documents/Folder\\ name\\ containing\\ space/myscript.txt`?

Comment: Open a __command prompt window__ and run `cmd /?`. The last paragraph on last help page output into __console window__ (not shell window) explains that a file name argument must be enclosed in double quotes on containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. And directory separator on Windows is the backslash character ``\``. Don't know if `Rscript` on Windows expects file names nevertheless with `/` as on Unix/Linux/Mac. `Rscript.exe "C:\Documents\Folder name containing space\myscript.txt"` __might__ work. (I could not test it because Rscript not installed.)

Comment: Thank you for having a look but it doesn't solve the problem. The issue I am having is not with R itself but rather in passing on the file path by the shell. using `"file path"` doesn't work, returning `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`. I am looking for a way for the shell to pass the file path that includes spaces. In the documentations it is specified the **Spaces are allowed in expression and file (but will need to be protected from the shell in use, if any, for example by enclosing the argument in quotes).** which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @rashid and @lit using the \\ doesn't solve the problem, instead returning the `C:/Documents/Folder\\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the file path in quotes? So `Rscript "C:/Documents/Folder name containing space/myscript.txt"`

Comment: @Steven Yes I have tried that and I get the message `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: @Mofi It is an executable (.exe) file

Comment: @GabrielOlshansky In my opinion `rscript.exe` has a bug if not supporting on Windows `"C:\Documents\Folder name containing space\myscript.txt"` with Windows directory separator nor `"C:/Documents/Folder name containing space/myscript.txt"` with Unix/Linux/Mac directory separator. You can additionally try `"C:\\Documents\\Folder name containing space\\myscript.txt"`. But if that also does not work, you better contact author of __Rscript__ and report this bug and use in the meantime the short 8.3 path/file name of that file to work around this bug.

Comment: @GabrielOlshansky One last try would be `"'C:/Documents/Folder name containing space/myscript.txt'"`. Windows command line interpreter `cmd.exe` does not support `'` to quote an argument with spaces as Linux shell interpreters like `bash`, `sh` or `ksh`. So double quotes must be used on Windows for an argument string with spaces. But perhaps __Rscript__ is so bad coded that it interprets only file names with spaces enclosed in `'` correct. And as __Rscript__ is ported from Unix, it might help to use as first argument `--` and as second argument the file name enclosed in `"`.

Comment: @Mofi I have tried all of that and I still get the same message. I think you are right, I am going to report the bug. Thank you for all the help, I will update the post when I hear back from them

Comment: @GabrielOlshansky did you get any results from reporting the bug? I'm having exactly the same issue after upgrading to R 3.5.0. I never had this issue before! i can't run Rscript with spaces in the names of folders and files.

Answer (score 3):

It is a BUG in R version 3.5.0 for Windows.
One workaround, apart from downgrading, is creating an R script with no spaces in its path and run the spaced one with `source()`:

```
## C:\Documents\Folder-name-no-space\myscript.txt
source("C:/Documents/Folder name containing space/myscript.txt")
```

Then you run it with:

```
Rscript C:\Documents\Folder-name-no-space\myscript.txt
```

or also:

```
Rscript C:/Documents/Folder-name-no-space/myscript.txt
```

You may also try the 8.3 filename. You can get it with:

```
for %I in ("C:/Documents/Folder name containing space/myscript.txt") do @echo %~sI
```

### UPDATE

Since 3.5.1 the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Forward slashes work just fine with R, so don't worry about backward slashes.  I've just verified and the following works at the CMD.exe terminal of Windows 8.1:

```
C:\Windows\System32> Rscript "C:/Users/hb/folder with spaces/script.R"
[1] "1+2+3"

C:\Windows\System32>
```

My best guess is that you've got the pathname incorrect. If it's a non-existing pathname, you do get:

```
C:\Windows\System32> Rscript --vanilla "C:/Users/hb/folder with spaces/non-existing.R"
Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:/Users/hb/folder with spaces/non-existing.R': No such file or directory
```

You can validate it from within R, e.g.

```
> file.exists("C:/Users/hb/folder with spaces/script.R")
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution**: install a newer version of R.

From the [version 3.5.1 release notes](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2018/000630.html), the relevant bug fix is described here:

> Allow file argument of Rscript to include space even when it is first on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Another convenient workaround was to create an alias for the portion of the path which contains spaces, i.e.:

```
SUBST k: "c:\Folder with Spaces"
rscript k:\scripts\program.R
```